# How to set Rounded Border for Blackberry BitmapField

Tags: blackberry

I trying to set rounded border for Blackberry Bitmap field.But it is not working for me.
I overriding paint method of Bitmap field.

```
g.drawRoundRect(0,0,HomeScreenIcons.barcode.getWidth(),HomeScreenIcons.barcode.getHeight(), 10, 10);
```

How can i set Border for Bitmap field in Blackberry.

Comment: do u mean to say rounded CORNERS..... then below is the solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a try this way:
 BitmapField bitf = new BitmapField();
 bitf.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(new XYEdges(6,6,6,6)));

Hope this helps...